# What am I doing wrong in this Twilioquest exercise? (sortOrder.js - JavaScript Begin)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, arguments, twilio

well, this is the problem:

> (TwillioQuest - Enable Beam 2 Problem)
> Create a script called sortOrder.js. This script will take two command
> line arguments - a pair of strings that should be compared to see
> which one comes first alphabetically (letter casing is not important).
>
> To test your script, you would execute it like this:
>
> ```
> node sortOrder.js cats dogs
> ```
>
> Your script should determine if the first string is before, after, or
> in the same position (equal) to the second string, alphabetically. For
> each case, you should print out a number with console.log as described
> below.
>
> - When the first argument is earlier in the alphabet than the second, your script should print -1.
> - When the first argument is the same as the second, your script should print 0.
> - When the first argument is later in the alphabet than the second, your function should print 1.

Basically, cats and dogs must output -1, dogs and cats output 1, dogs and dog outputs 0. It must ignore case sensitive.

Then, I tried two different approaches:

**1- Creating two lists (one before the sorting method and one after) and printing in sequence with IFs:**

```
let aftSort = [];
let bfSort = [];

const first = process.argv[2].toLocaleLowerCase();
const second = process.argv[3].toLocaleLowerCase();

aftSort.push(first);
aftSort.push(second);
bfSort = [...aftSort];
aftSort.sort();

if (bfSort[0][0] == bfSort[1][0]){ //checking if the first letters are the same
console.log(0)};

if (bfSort[0] == aftSort[0]) { //checking if the first word is still first after sorting
console.log(-1)};

if(bfSort[0] == aftSort[1]){ //checking if the first word is the second after sorting
console.log(1)};
```

**2- Creating the same lists but printing only once after an analyze function**:

```
let aftSort = [];
let bfSort = [];

const first = process.argv[2].toLocaleLowerCase();
const second = process.argv[3].toLocaleLowerCase();

aftSort.push(first);
aftSort.push(second);
bfSort = [...aftSort];
aftSort.sort();

function analyze(aftSort,bfSort) {
    if (bfSort[0][0] == bfSort[1][0]){ //in case bothe initial letters are the same
        console.log(0);
        return;}
    else {
        if (bfSort[0] == aftSort[0]) { //in case the initial string is in the first position after sorting
            console.log(-1);
            return;} else if (bfSort[0] == aftSort[1]) { //in case the initial string is in the second place after sorting
                    console.log(1);
                    return;}

}


}

analyze(aftSort,bfSort);
```

**Edit: Now, even a third method using only the first letters and no list which also doesn't work:**

```
const firstValue = process.argv[2].toLowerCase();
const secondValue = process.argv[3].toLowerCase();

function analyze(firstValue, secondValue) {
    if (firstValue[0][0] == secondValue[0][0]) {console.log(0)} //comparing first letters
    else {
        if (firstValue[0][0] < secondValue[0][0]) { //comparing the values
            console.log(-1)}
        else if (firstValue[0][0] > secondValue[0][0]){console.log(1)};

    }
}

analyze(firstValue, secondValue)
```

However, even passing my own tests, I keep receiving this error in the game:

> Your script must print "1" when the first argument passed to it
> appears alphabetically later than the second argument.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

const firstValue = process.argv[2] //leave it like this. No .toLowerCase()

const secondValue = process.argv[3] //same here. No .toLowerCase()

let result = 0;  //to have the result stored here.

within if and else if you can compare firstValue.tolowerCase() and secondValue.toLowerCase()

update your Variable 'result' by -1 or 0 or 1, depending on the comparison.

don't forget to display result with console.log at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the third approach again, but not considering only the first letters:

```
const sortFirstArg = process.argv[2].toLocaleLowerCase();
const sortSecondArg = process.argv[3].toLocaleLowerCase();
let answer = 0;

if (sortFirstArg < sortSecondArg){
    answer = -1;
}

if (sortFirstArg > sortSecondArg){
    answer = 1;
}

console.log(answer);
```

Apparently they don't want a real alphabetical order...

Edit: This one worked.